# Line gets painted in wrong place when not maximised

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I have extended `JPanel` and overriden the `paint` method in order to draw some extra lines between the locations of certain `JButton`s within the panel. However, the lines are only drawn correctly when the gui is maximized, otherwise they are drawn at totally the wrong offset.

To paint the line I am using ('rootNode' and 'child' are both `JButton`, `g` is the `Graphics` parameter of the overriden `paint` method):

```
Point sourcePoint = new Point(rootNode.getLocation());
Point destPoint = new Point(child.getLocation());
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(sourcePoint, rootNode.getParent());
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(destPoint, child.getParent());
g.drawLine(sourcePoint.x, sourcePoint.y, destPoint.x, destPoint.y);
```

Picture of incorrect lines when not maximised: http://postimage.org/image/ws0yo9chf/
Picture of correct when maximised: http://postimage.org/image/fq84m5xmb/

Comment: you should override `paintComponent(..)` of `JComponent` and do painting there, not in `paint(..)` method. and dont forget the all important `super.paintComponent(g);`as first line in overriden `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: overriding paintComponent results in the same effect. I'll upload pictures now..

Comment: no matter if its the same (than something else is at fault) never draw in `paint()` unless for a very good reason! Please see here for more: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Added pictures to original post

Comment: Why are you converting to screen coordinates?

Comment: I thought that g.drawline requires the screen coordinates, maybe (probably) I am wrong

Comment: It uses `Graphics` coordinate system. From the docs: "Draws a line, ... in this graphics context's coordinate system", which will be the component's coords, unless something has been done to change this.  If you comment out these two lines, I'm guessing you will be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to cover off on the comments.  I don't think you want to convert to screen coordinates in this case.

The `Graphics` context for the `paintComponent(...)` method will most likely be set up for the component coordinate system.

JavaDoc for `Graphics.drawLine(...)` states:

> Draws a line, using the current color, between the points (x1, y1) and
>   (x2, y2) in this graphics context's coordinate system.

Unless you've done something to change it via `Graphics.translate(...)` or `Graphics2D.setTransform(...)`, the coordinate system will be set up for the component.

Apart from being in the wrong place, converting to screen coordinates will have the effect of changing the location of the lines depending on where the window is on the screen :)